# Which one is correct-

Tags: word-choice

I’m confused about the following-
Would it be “Lightning fast deliveries like these” or “lightning fast deliveries like this”?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you're comparing it to. 
If multiple deliveries are being described as lightning fast, go for "like these".

If you have received a bunch of packages delivered to your home much faster than you expected, you say: "Lightning fast deliveries like these cheer me up." However if you have received just one package, you say: "Lightning fast deliveries like this are always appreciated."